# Python - how to change email text typeface

Tags: python, email

I'm writing an app that generates full report and it's summary, and sends them via email.
A summary is sent as text in email, and a full report is sent as attachement.
I found an example ([link](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/757)) that works great, but I would need to set font's typeface of an email message as monospaced (e.g. 'Courier New').

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

Email will send as both plaintext and as HTML. A plaintext email renderer will generally be rendered in a monospace font, but there is no guarantee of that. More importantly, there is nothing you can do to change what font the plaintext will display in.

If your recipient is reading mail in an HTML capable email client, you should be able to accomplish that by wrapping `<font face="Courier New, Courier, monospace"></font>` (a font tag) around the pieces of the email you'd like to have in Courier. In the method provided, you would simply have:

```
text = '<font face="Courier New, Courier, monospace">' + text + '</font>'
```

If you wanted that to be the whole email.

Answer (score -2):

```
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.login("email", "password")
server.sendmail("email", "email", "message")
server.quit()
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -8):

You should generate E-Mail in HTML format and insert needed tags

Comment: Very partial answer (how about providing an example?) + not all clients support HTML emails.

Comment: "You should write some code to do what it is you want to." -- Your answer is just about as useful