# How to change font in python email

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib

I'd like to change the font size of a specific word in an email I'm sending using python.  This is the code I have so far...

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("user@gmail.com", "password")
SUBJECT = "The subject"
TEXT = "I would like to change THIS word to bold"
message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(SUBJECT, TEXT)
server.sendmail("user@gmail.com", recipients, message)
server.quit()
```

Is there any way I can change the word "THIS" in the text line to bold (and bigger font), but keep the other words the original font?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - how to change email text typeface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011992/python-how-to-change-email-text-typeface)

Comment: ...and the next question as to *how* is answered in [Sending HTML email using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python).

Answer (score 0):

1.

You can use this code to start bold:
`\033[1m` and this to end it: `\033[0m`.

E.g. `str = "normal " + '\033[1m' + "bold " + '\033[0m' + "normal"`.

This answer may help you: [print bold text in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924173/how-do-i-print-bold-text-in-python)

2.

Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python) using HTML formatting. It is quite simple. In fact you need only the HTML  tag to format words in bold.

However the first method works on my machine.

Comment: well you might have a duplicate answer here...
plus this will fail like my answer... cause he is not printing the result....

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I wrote while you're doing the same so I haven't seen your answer. I am going to edit my answer adding some docs' links

Comment: What machine are you using?

Comment: Are you on Windows, Mac OS or Linux?

Comment: However I think it is not related with your os