# Python print text in fixed width in mail

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, smtplib

I want the print out this in a pretty way and send out through mail.  `string formatting` is applied.

here is my code:

```
"{:<40s}".format("   Expected total delivery:") + "|" + "{:>10s}".format(`number`) + "{:>10s}".format(" (" + `percentage` + ")") + "\n" + \
"{:<40s}".format("   Current delivery:") + "|" + "{:>10s}".format(`number`) + "{:>10s}".format(" (" + `percentage` + ")") + "\n" + \
"{:<40s}".format("   Suggested Daily Delivery:") + "|" + "{:>10s}".format(`number`)
```

Expected outcome: 

   `Expected total delivery:             |  number (percentage)
   Suggested Daily Delivery:            |  number (percentage)
   Current delivery:                    |  number`

Real situation in the mail sent:

[screencap from mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB0Um.png)

I think this would be an issue caused by mailing. However, i cannot figure this out.

```
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
```

Any suggestion can be advised? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason the formatting looks good to you in code is because your code is monospaced. The email may be rendered variable-width, on the other hand, and you have no control. Your only solution is to use HTML to set the font to monospace. See [this similar Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011992/python-how-to-change-email-text-typeface).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. i will to change my approach first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing text formatting and rendering font.  The text formatting is the sequence of ASCII codes your program produces; this is what you handle with the "string formatting" you posted.  The rendering, how those characters affect what you see on the screen, is an interaction between the text you send through and the display software.  You're using MIME formatting.

You need to look into the MIMEText documentation to find the fixed-width fonts supported on your interface and display device.  This is almost certainly a simple change, replacing `plain` with an appropriate font, such as `courier`.